# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT swift

Tags: swift, uitextfielddelegate

I was trying to center the text in the middle of a view, but instead, received an error. Here's my code as a reference.

```
let textbox = UITextField()
    textbox.text = "Hello"
    textbox.sizeToFit()
    textbox.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textboxView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    textbox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textboxView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    textbox.delegate = self
    self.textboxView.addSubview(textbox)
```

Comment: which line you get the error?

Comment: Yes, more detail. Where are you creating `textbox`? With what you posted, nobody can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was in a rush, but someone else helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot constraint a view relative to another view unless they are first related.

You need to add the subview first before setting the constraints

```
let textbox = UITextField()
textbox.text = "Hello"
textbox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.textboxView.addSubview(textbox)
textbox.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textboxView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
textbox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textboxView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
textbox.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t given lot of detail surrounding the rest of your view controller, so you may have already added it somewhere else.

However, when using autolayout constraints you must turn off auto masking.

```
textbox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

You should also add the textbox as a subview prior to setting constraints.